# knockout validation happens after element is added to model

Tags: knockout.js

Here is a fiddle that shows part of my issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/Nv2pW/

There is an input box with a button; the input box should validate mandatory and email address. In my live site, it does validate, but not until after the item in the input  box has been added to the emailCC array, which is too late - if it's not a valid email address, I don't want it in the model. (in the fiddle, the validation is not firing at all, but I'm not sure why). How can I prevent the input box item from being added to the emailCC array if it's not valid?

part of the js code is here:

```
 function emailViewModel() {
 var self = this;
 self.emailAddress = ko.observable("test").extend({
     required: true
 }).extend({
     email: true
 });
 self.emailCC = ko.observableArray([]);

 self.addCC = function () {
     if (this.emailAddress() !== "")
     self.emailCC.push(new EmailAddress(self.emailAddress()));
     self.emailAddress(""); //clear text box
 };
 }
 ko.applyBindings(new emailViewModel());

 function EmailAddress(name) {
 this.name = name;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made changes to fix your issue which is working fine.

with the use of

```
  isValid() method achieved your objective
```

### [check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naveenkumarm/VeBSf/)

Feel free to mark it as answer and to click up-link if its solved your issue.